# How to add google maps to active admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am using active-admin in my rails app and want to plot the (lat, lot) on a google maps. Can someone please guide me how to go about it.

Here is my booking_geo_locations.rb file

```
ActiveAdmin.register BookingGeoLocation do
    show do
        attributes_table do
          row :id
          row :user_id
          row :date_pickup      
          row :location_pickup
          row :date_dropoff
          row :location_dropoff
          row :location_pickup_latitude
          row :location_dropoff_latitude 
          row :driver_price

          end
      end
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity's sake, my example is based off of a `rails g scaffold Post location:string latitude:float longitude:float` migration.

Add this to the end of *config/initializers/active_admin.rb* (after the last `end`):

```rb
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  javascripts = Array.wrap("//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#{ENV['GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY']}&libraries=places")
  javascripts += ActiveAdmin.application.javascripts.to_a
  ActiveAdmin.application.javascripts.replace javascripts
end
```

You will have to restart your server for this to take effect. Note that this makes use of an environment variable, which you will have to set as well.

Next, in *app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js.coffee* you want to do something along the lines of:

```
jQuery ->
  input = document.getElementById("post_location");
  if input
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autocomplete.addListener "place_changed", ->
      $("#post_latitude").val(autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lat());
      $("#post_longitude").val(autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lng());
```

When you go to add a new post, you will get an as you type dropdown provided by Google Maps. Selecting an option from there will fill your latitude and longitude fields—it's a good idea to make these read-only so your users get visual confirmation of the coordinates being selected, but cannot change the data.

NB: To implement this on your `BookingGeoLocation` model, you'd need two more columns in your table,`location_pickup_longitude` and `location_dropoff_longitude`. Make sure these are of type `Float`.